# Getting text to copy to multiple text boxes on separate artboards in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I have a file that I use that has multiple artboards. I type info on page one and it copies the same information on the additional artboards. I need to know how to set this feature up in a new file. So far the "linking" just causes the text to carry over. I want the same info on every page.

Comment: Is the text in your document that does this a symbol or a linked document?

Comment: I added a transform-effect based answer to the referenced question.

Answer (score 0):

*Probably overkill in this instance (see other comments about using symbols).*

How about using [variables](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/data-driven-graphics-templates-variables.html)? It's like InDesign's Data Merge ugly cousin. It's a bit annoying to use without [variable importer](https://github.com/Silly-V/Adobe-Illustrator/blob/master/Variable%20Importer/VariableImporter.jsx) though. Unless you like typing XML :3

It's great if you have several instances of stuff you want to change outside of AI, maybe in Excel or something that writes CSVs.